# Extract parameterized data from string using python from AWS Lambda EVENT

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dataframe

This is the raw string

```
"body": "----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n\r\n payment_received_unrecognised\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"err\"\r\n\r\n An incorrect bitcoin amount has been received\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"private_key_hash\"\r\n\r\n sadf65d4sf56sd4f6sd54fsdfs....\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"box\"\r\n\r\n 111\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"boxtype\"\r\n\r\n criptoBox\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"order\"\r\n\r\n \r\n----------------------------6547984164*94652165481564\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user\"\r\n\r\n ADAM\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userformat\"\r\n\r\n \r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"usercountry\"\r\n\r\n \r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"period\"\r\n\r\n \r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"amount\"\r\n\r\n 0.0016\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"amountusd\"\r\n\r\n 152.45\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coinlabel\"\r\n\r\n BTC\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coinname\"\r\n\r\n bitcoin\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"addr\"\r\n\r\n 14dt4cSbvwghDcETJDuvFGHe5bCsCPR1jW\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"tx\"\r\n\r\n 6f1c6f34189a27446d18e25b9c79db90be55b0bb775b1768b5aa4520f23d71a8\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"confirmed\"\r\n\r\n 0\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"timestamp\"\r\n\r\n 1422623712\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"date\"\r\n\r\n 30 January 2015\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"datetime\"\r\n\r\n 2015-01-30 13: 15: 12\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229--\r\n"
    }
```

I need to fetch value in DICT format, like

```
{
'status': 'payment_received_unrecognised',
'boxtype': 'Criptobox'
}
```

**I am unable to extract data as i wanted... i need suggestion how to extract data from the string?**

N.B: here string like "276035280975268320779229" changes every time i send request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `re.findall`:

```py
inp = '"body": "----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n\r\n payment_received_unrecognised\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"err\"\r\n\r\n An incorrect bitcoin amount has been received\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"private_key_hash\"\r\n\r\n sadf65d4sf56sd4f6sd54fsdfs....\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"box\"\r\n\r\n 111\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"boxtype\"\r\n\r\n criptoBox\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"order\"\r\n\r\n \r\n----------------------------6547984164*94652165481564\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user\"\r\n\r\n ADAM\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userformat\"\r\n\r\n \r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"usercountry\"\r\n\r\n \r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"period\"\r\n\r\n \r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"amount\"\r\n\r\n 0.0016\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"amountusd\"\r\n\r\n 152.45\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coinlabel\"\r\n\r\n BTC\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coinname\"\r\n\r\n bitcoin\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"addr\"\r\n\r\n 14dt4cSbvwghDcETJDuvFGHe5bCsCPR1jW\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"tx\"\r\n\r\n 6f1c6f34189a27446d18e25b9c79db90be55b0bb775b1768b5aa4520f23d71a8\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"confirmed\"\r\n\r\n 0\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"timestamp\"\r\n\r\n 1422623712\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"date\"\r\n\r\n 30 January 2015\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"datetime\"\r\n\r\n 2015-01-30 13: 15: 12\r\n----------------------------276035280975268320779229--\r\n"'
my_dict = dict(re.findall(r'\bname="(status|boxtype)"\s+(\S+)', inp))

print(my_dict)
```

This prints:

```
{'status': 'payment_received_unrecognised', 'boxtype': 'criptoBox'}
```

Comment: You could additionally format your regex with the keys that you are searching for, e.g.: `dict(re.findall("({})\"\s+(\S+)".format("|".join(list_of_keys)), inp))` this way you don't have to type every key you are searching for ;)